# Why does the time process to complete the program differ between usleep and sleep in c?

Tags: c, sleep

```
#include<stdio.h>
 
main()
{
   printf("Sleep for 5 milisecond to exit.\n");
   sleep(0.005);
   printf("usleep for 5 milisecond to exit.\n");
   usleep(5000);
   return 0;
}
```

the sleep function takes more time to execute comparatively to the usleep function which takes seconds?

Comment: With a setup this simple, any kind of "noise" (cold caches, dynamic loading of libraries, terminal init, ...) would easily drown out any actual difference you might see. Profiling is an art in itself....

Comment: Include `<unistd.h>` and try again. It's undefined as it is. Also `sleep` takes seconds, not a double.

Comment: In your case probably it is about conversion double to integer, be aware that it is about the OS and its current load. It is about suspension for "at least" 5ms ... So you have to check some average delay, not single measurement.

Comment: Voting to close this as simple typo since you didn't even check how these functions work... you can't just take a guess or assume that a function works like you want it to. You have to study how it is actually implemented by reading the friendly `man`.

Comment: ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` using gcc) and hede them!

Comment: Add `#include <unistd.h>` and you will get nearly equal delays(0ms vs 5ms).
But neither `sleep` nor `usleep` are designed for accurate timing purpose. If you need accurate timer, search for `High Precision Event Timer (HPET)`.

Comment: @chqrlie And yet my answer in that link is saying the very same things as your answer here. I've written a more beginner-friendly explanation here: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sleep` system call is defined in `<unistd.h>` on POSIX systems as:

```
unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);
```

If you do not include `<unistd.h>`, the `sleep` function is not defined and the compiler, using obsolete pre-ansi semantics, infers a prototype of `int sleep(double)`. This has undefined behavior. The actual `unsigned int` value received by the system could be anything at all, this can cause a long pause as you observe, but it could also crash depending on the system's ABI...

If you include a proper definition by including `<unistd.h>`, the `0.005` double argument will be implicitly converted to `0` and the program will not pause at all.

Note also that omitting the return type of `main()` is an obsolete feature. Avoid this old style programming and upgrade your compiler.

It is recommended to enable all warnings to avoid such silly bugs: use the `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` options with `gcc` and `clang`.

Note also that both `sleep` and `usleep` may cause the program to stop for longer than specified in the argument, depending on current system load.